# q.setOrder(...) extremely slow in DataNucleus + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jdo, datanucleus, nosql

I have a latest stable DataNucleus (3.0.1) with MongoDB datastore and JDO implementation.
The collection has around 1M documents.
The "id" field is indexed.
This code takes several minutes to execute:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(CellMeasurement.class);
q.setOrdering("id descending");
q.setRange(0, count);
Collection<CellMeasurement> result = (Collection<CellMeasurement>)q.execute();
```

if I remove the `q.setOrdering(...)` everything is ok, for `count=1000` it takes around a second to load.

It looks like DN does the in-memory reordering, does it have any sense ? MongoDB itself orders instantly by this indexed field, the API supports ordering..

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Obviously 3.0.1 doesn't qualify as "latest stable" (Aug 2011) when there are releases every month more or less, and every release is "stable"

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, I'm using 3.2.0 m2 build. I've checked the current trunk as well and it has the same TODOs, so it won't wok anyways. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the log (for any application) would obviously reveal much; in this case what query is actually performed. In this case it would tell you easily enough that ordering is not currently implemented to execute in-datastore.

Obviously anybody could contribute to such codebase that has been open source since its first release. org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper method "compileOrdering" is where you need to implement that, and then attach a patch to a JIRA issue when you're done. Thx

Comment: Unfortunately right now I'm in a final step of project development and don't have time to investigate the DN plugins. You're right, this function has the TODO and thus the sorting is being handled in memory. The same for .setRange(), by the way. 
Right now I implemented this features locally using the native mongodb library.
When I finish the project I'll try to contribute to the store plugin.
Thanks.